# Create a graph plot with nodes of long format data

Tags: r, igraph

Having a dataset like this one:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
                  snames = c("stockA","stockB","stockC","stockA","stockB","stockC"),
                  var1 = c(0.13,1.2,-1.5,3.45,-0.26,-2.1), 
                  var2 = c(-2.1,2.34,3.56,-1.53,-0.48,-0.29), 
                  var3 = c(0.04,-3.45,-0.22,-0.29,1.34,0.32), 
                  var4 = c(2.14,-1.34,-4.35,-1.56,0.13,-2.35), 
                  var5 = c(1.53,1.24,-0.32,-0.3,-4.25,-2.49))
```

How is it possible to create a graph having as nodes the values of snames and edges will be the values of var1, var2, var3, var4, var5?

Comment: I don't understand the data structure, the nodes are `snames` and the edges, say, `var1` go from what node to what node?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic node: stockA -> stockB

Comment: Yes, but the edge is 0.13 or 1.2?

Comment: Your logic here might be more clear if you included what you've tried so far—otherwise this is a fairly vague task you're asking people to do